# Utilizar un contador haciendo recursión en Java

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de restas sucesivas, ingreso 2 números(dividendo y divisor), y estos números en la función recursiva se van restando sucesivamente hasta que el 'dividendo' sea menor al divisor, una vez que es menor me retorna el valor(residuo o resto). El problema es que necesito llevar un contador de las veces que hace esto pero no entiendo como lograrlo para que me devuelva un contador con la cantidad de veces que hizo las restas sucesivas ya que la función solo retorna un único valor.

```
static int restaSucesiva(int dividiendo, int divisor) {
        int resta,contador;
        resta = dividiendo - divisor;
        contador = 0;
        if (resta < divisor) {
            return resta;
            
        } else {
            return restaSucesiva(dividiendo - divisor, divisor);
            
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args){

 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int dividiendo, divisor, cociente, resta, contador;

        System.out.println("Ingrese dividiendo: ");
        dividiendo = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese divisor: ");
        divisor = sc.nextInt();

        contador = 0;
        resta = restaSucesiva(dividiendo, divisor);


        System.out.println("El resto es: " + resta);
        System.out.println("El cociente es: " + contador);
}
```

Comment: Podrías llevar la cuenta con un entero estático, el cual tendrías que restablecer antes de usar la función. También existe la posibilidad de crear una clase para no tener que reiniciar el contador.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El contador solo tiene existencia dentro de la llamada actual a la función. Deberías revisar el concepto de ámbito para entenderlo mejor.

La forma de solucionarlo es ubicando el contador en otro lugar. Como variable estática dentro de la clase en la que está tu código, fuera de la función.

Quedaría algo así:

```
public class Programa {
    static int contador = 0;

    static int restaSucesiva(int dividiendo, int divisor){
       int resta = dividendo - divisor;
       if (resta < divisor){
           contador++;
           return resta;
       }
       // Else no hace falta porque solo hay 2 caminos con returns dentro. Si quieres puedes agregarlo.
       contador++;
       return restaSucesiva(resta, divisor);
    }

    static void main(String[] args){
        ...
        contador = 0;
        restaSucesiva(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Si entendí bien, la variable contador se declara en la clase y luego yo puedo acceder a ella desde el main debido a que está dentro de la clase declarada eso me hace que sea una variable del tipo estática?

Comment: Eso y que sea estática. Como la función main es estática, solo puede acceder a los parámetros y otras cosas estáticas. Cuando puedas digerir más información, verás que hay algunas cosas más que determinan de dónde puedes acceder a una variable o una función. Es con lo que tienes que lidiar por programar en un lenguaje orientado a objetos.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando quieres actualizar valores de una variable el cual se encuentra en otro método, lo que tienes que hacer el crear un `atributo de clase`, en el caso de tu ejercicio la variable tiene que ser `static` la razón porque lo vas usar dentro del método `main` que es `static`.
Trata de no crear variables de más cuando esas variables pueden ser reemplazados por una operación, tus variables innecesarios son (resta, cociente).
Te dejo el código con las correcciones.

```
public class DivisionRecursiva {
    private static int contador=0;
    
    static int restaSucesiva(int dividendo, int divisor) {        
        
        if (dividendo < divisor) {
            return dividendo;            
        }        
            contador++;
            return restaSucesiva(dividendo - divisor, divisor);
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args){

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            int dividendo, divisor;

            System.out.println("Ingrese dividiendo: ");
            dividendo = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese divisor: ");
            divisor = sc.nextInt();              
            
            System.out.println("El resto es: " + restaSucesiva(dividendo, divisor));
            System.out.println("El cociente es: "+contador);
    }
}
```

**Otro detalle sin relevancia**
Se llama `dividendo` no `dividiendo`, lo digo por como declaraste tu variable.

Answer (score 0):

No estas incrementando el contador en ningun momento. Por cada iteracion debes aumentar el valor en 1:

```
static int restaSucesiva(int dividiendo, int divisor) {
    int resta,contador;
    resta = dividiendo - divisor;
    contador = 0;
    if (resta < divisor) {
        contador++;
        return resta;
        
        
    } else {
        contador++;
        return restaSucesiva(dividiendo - divisor, divisor);
        
    }
    System.out.println("Numero de iteraciones: "+contador);
}
```

Comment: Claro lo intente de esa forma, pero no entiendo como lograr que en el programa principal me devuelva esa incrementacion en el contador.

Comment: Si te fijas, en el main le estas asignando 0 al contador, así que siempre sera 0 porque en ningún momento lo incrementas. Si quieres el valor lo puedes imprimir en el mismo método al realizar la ultima iteración. En este caso, asumo que quieres incrementar el contador tanto en el if como en el else, luego de eso deberías imprimir el valor final del contador. Modificaré la respuesta para que observes como debería quedar.

Comment: Ernesto, no tiene sentido aumentar el contador luego del return, puesto que se sale de la función y la instrucción no llega a ejecutarse

Comment: @Mateo tienes razón, se me había pasado por alto. Ya esta editada la respuesta.

Comment: @Ketzell acabo de notar también que no estas ciclando dentro del método. Debes usar un While o un for hasta que se cumpla la condición, que en este caso es hasta que el dividendo sea menos que el divisor.